# Problems with rounding a float number

Tags: c, floating-point

I have the following source code but the result is not rounding to 2 decimal places.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    float x1=0;
    float x2 = 0;
    float result=0;
    x1 = 8961.650391;

    result = x1 * 100 + 0.5;
    result = (float)floor(result);
    printf("Result = <%f>\n", result);

    result = result/100;
    x2 = result;
    printf("x2 = <%f>\n", x2);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help to resolve the problem.

```
Result = <896165.000000>
x2 = <8961.650391>
```

How can obtain x3 = 8961.650000?

Answer (score 3):

use "%0.2f" instead of %f , it will print value upto 2 decimal

```
x2= roundf(result * 100) / 100;
printf("x2 = <%0.2f>\n", x2);
```

Comment: But I need to round the value, so i need x2 = <8961.65>

Comment: Added the roundf function which will help you to round as well. , see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

`float` can typically represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different numbers exactly.
 After all, it is [typically encoded using 32-bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

8961.65 is not one of them.  The closest `float` to 8961.65 is  `8961.650390625f`.  The below shows the previous and subsequent `float`.

To print a `float` to the nearest 0.01, use `"%.2f"` as suggest well by [@pritesh agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070712/2410359).

Recommend rounding with `rint()` or `round()`.

```
int main(void) {
  float x = 8961.650391f;
  float x100 = rint(x * 100.0);
  float result = x100 / 100.0f;

  printf("%f %.2f\n", nextafterf(x, 0), nextafterf(x, 0));
  printf("%f %.2f\n", x, x);
  printf("%f %.2f\n", nextafterf(x, x * 2), nextafterf(x, x * 2));
  printf("%f %.2f\n", x100, x100);
  printf("%f %.2f\n", result, result);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
8961.649414 8961.65
8961.650391 8961.65
8961.651367 8961.65
896165.000000 896165.00
8961.650391 8961.65
```

---

> How can obtain x3 = 8961.650000?

`x3` *cannot* have the exact value of `8961.650000`.  To *print* a value, rounded to 2 decimal places followed by 4 zeros, the below can be used, but it is a bit of [chicanery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chicanery).

```
  printf("%.2f0000\n", 8961.650390625f);
  // output 8961.650000
```

Comment: That see the reason for:

Comment: x3 = atof("8961.65");
 
printf("x3 = %f\n",x3);  >> x3 = 8961.650391

Comment: How can obtain x3 = 8961.650000

Comment: @user5240895 [It cannot be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070669/problems-with-rounding-a-float-number/45071691?noredirect=1#comment77117499_45071691) , exactly.  `x3` is a `float`. There are infinite numbers, `float` cannot represent all of them only a sub-set of them.  It cannot **exactly** encode the number 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.0, nor can it encode the number `8961.65` and not even `0.1`.  The closest value to 8961.65, that a `float` can encode is 8961.650390625.  `printf("x3 = %f\n",x3)` simple  prints the value to the nearest 0.000001 or `"8961.650391"`.